# Value from File is not matching with variable value

Tags: java, file

I am trying to match file value with variable value. But somehow it is not matching. I checked it is reading file and holding value in the variable but not matching. Not sure if I have to use contains function.

```
int rcdMatch = 0;
String st;
String extdeductamt = "1000";
BufferedReader Br = null;
File objFile = new File(strPlanFile + NewFileNmae);
Br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(objFile));
List < String > list = new ArrayList < String > ();
LineNumberReader lineNumberReader = new LineNumberReader(new FileReader(objFile));
lineNumberReader.skip(Long.MAX_VALUE);
int lines = lineNumberReader.getLineNumber();
while ((st = Br.readLine()) != null) {
 arraylist = st;
 String amt = arraylist.substring(0, arraylist.length() - 392);
 list.add(amt);
 Set < String > unique = new HashSet < String > (list);
 for (String key: unique) {
  rcdMatch = 0;
  if (key.trim().toString().equals(stvar)) {
   String adjAmt = arraylist.substring(34, arraylist.length() - 348);
   System.out.println("Adjustment Amount 1 is: " + adjAmt);
   if (extdeductamt.trim().toString().equals(adjAmt.trim().toString())) {
    rcdMatch++;
   }
   if (!(rcdMatch == 0)) {
    System.out.println("PASS Amount is displayed: " + adjAmt);
   }
  }
  break;
 }
}
```

Comment: Please share the content of the file.

Comment: What does this have to do with sql server?

Comment: Actually,    String extdeductamt = "1000"; coming from database and file is fixed length file Forexample - SAVAL   00000080000002001 PR1     1000